# .getJSON not processing file

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

hello I am new to using jQuery to read a JSON file. I am using the following code:

```
  $.getJSON('updateProfile.js', function(data) {
    var Options = [];
    $.each(data.Options, function(key, val) {
    alert('we have data for ' + val.id + ' and ' + val.label);
     });
```

I have used a JSON validation tool and the file is valid. I have used chrome and firebug in FF to confirm the file is getting a 200 status. however when I put a break point on the .getJSON call, the code gets bypassed.

I have used a local tomcat server as well as putting this ona actually server all perform the same way.

Here is the the JSON I am trying to read

```
{"Options":[
"title": "User Profile",
"description": "Your preferences can be modified below. Click on the section on the left. This will present the details on the right. Once you have updated your profile, click the Save button to save your changes.",
"id": "userprofileStackTabs",
"children": [
    {
        "id": "up001",
        "linkID": "namePhones",
        "label": "Name and Phones",
        "description": "",
        "default": "true"
    },
    {
        "id": "up002",
        "linkID": "password",
        "label": "Password",
        "description": " "
    },
    {
        "id": "up003",
        "linkID": "physAddrss",
        "label": "Physical Address",
        "description": " "
    },
    {
        "id": "up004",
        "linkID": "dfShippingAddrss",
        "label": "Default Shipping Address",
        "description": " "
    },
    {
        "id": "up005",
        "linkID": "cpgnPref",
        "label": "Campaign Preferences",
        "description": " "
    },
    {
        "id": "up006",
        "linkID": "appPref",
        "label": "Application Preferences",
        "description": " "
    },
    {
        "id": "up007",
        "linkID": "langPref",
        "label": "Language Preferences",
        "description": " "
    },
    {
        "id": "up008",
        "linkID": "agentLic",
        "label": "Agent Licenses",
        "description": " "
    },
    {
        "id": "up009",
        "linkID": "searchPref",
        "label": "Search Preferences",
        "description": " "
    },
    {
        "id": "up010",
        "linkID": "socMedAcct",
        "label": "Social Media Accounts",
        "description": " "
    }
],
"buttons": [
    {
        "id": "upButn_Save",
        "label": "Save"
    },
    {
        "id": "upButn_Cancel",
        "label": "Cancel"
    }
]
```

]}

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Youre JSON is malformed. You cant have string keys inside an array `[]`.

Comment: add an error callback ( `$.getJSON(...).fail(function(){console.log(arguments);});` ) and inspect the arguments.

Comment: What json validation tool did you use so that i won't suggest it? (if it does indeed say the given json is valid)

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure why are you creating that Options array inside $.get .which i think is not need and your are not using it at all...

try this

```
$.each(data.Options[0].children, function(key, val) {
   alert('we have data for ' + val.id + ' and ' + val.label);
 });
```

you are tyring to get the id and label of children which is inside Options array `[0]`.. so loop through the chilren array of obecjt and get it..